# Integration testing with Nodejs, express and supertest

Tags: javascript, node.js, integration-testing

I'm actually creating an application and I need to make some integration tests.

I'm actually wondering how should I do to avoid the real behaviour of my express call back routes.

Example: admitting that I want to post a data on an express route and check that I get a HTTP 200 response code but without really adding the object to my database.

EDIT: I m using supertest (https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest)

How can I do?

```
request
    .post('/users') 
        .send({
            message : JSON.stringify({
                date: Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000),
                    type_fiche: 'test',
                    id_fiche: 123
                })
            })
            .expect(200)
            .end(done);
       });
```

EDIT 2: Is it possible to make something like a mock? Like faking a request?

You know that if I post something, it's that I need to insert something in my database right ?

I dont want to insert anything at all during myintegration tests, just test the result http response code.

I mean, admiting that I have an url like `/client`, and I post a new client on it. It will create a new row in the table. I dont want any row to be inserted, but I need to test the response code of the request.

Is that possible?

Comment: I cannot understand your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding [sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) into the mix or any other mocking library of your choice. It will probably require quite a bit of refactoring in order to inject the mocked components.

The main idea is to mock user repository which encapsulates all db communication with user data and mock it in tests. Then you will inject mocked repository into router and test express app with supertest. Check out the example of testing imaginary user API for GET request.

```
var routerFactory = require('../path/to/router/factory');
describe('app router', function () {
var app, repository, router;

  beforeEach(function () {
    app = require('express')();
    repository = createFakeUserRepository();
    router = createRotuter(repository);    
  });

 describe('getting user by id', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
   app.use('/test'm router);
   testedApp = supertest(app);
  });

  describe('GET /user/id', function (){
    beforeEach('setup for valid response', function () {
       repository.getById.returns(Promise.resolve({ expected: 'valid response' }))
 })
     it('returns 200', function (done){
        testedApp.get('/test/user/id')
         .expect(200, JSON.stringify({expected: 'valid response'}), done);
     })
    })
  })
 })
})


function createFakeUserRepository() {
  return {
    getById(): sinon:stub()
    save(): sinon:stub()
  };
}

function createRouter(fakeUserRepository) {
  return routerFactory(fakeUserRepository);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nock module. Its simple to use and you can get whatever data you want and you can test it.

```
Ex: nock('http://example.com')
  .get('/users')
  .query(true)
  .reply({results: [{id: 'pgte'}]});
```

Inside supertest you can test the 'id' value. For error cases you can use replyWithError. You can get more details here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock